# Headers within booklet template

Tags: header-footer, templates, geometry, booklet

Maybe this is trivial, but I'm not able to set a customized header within the booklet package.
Here my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{centering}
\geometry{width =108.5mm,height=170mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[noprint]{booklet}
%\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet}%
%\nofiles
\pagespersignature{4}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{My special header}}
\begin{document}
    \setpdftargetpages
    \clearpage page1
    \clearpage page2
    \clearpage page3
    \clearpage page4
\end{document}
```

How can I make the headers appear?

Comment: If I add `\pagestyle{fancy}` to your MWE the header appears.

Comment: If `booklet` works for you at all, congratulations!

Comment: @cfr : I've no experience. I just know about the existence of `booklet` and `pdfpages`. Do you think that  `pdfpages` is better, or do you have some other alternatives?

Comment: @amorvincomni I used to use `booklet`, but it ceased working for me ages ago and I now stick to `pdfpages`. However, so long as it works for you, I don't see why you should use `pdfpages` instead.

Comment: @cfr Indeed with printing  modality `booklet` do not work: the headers are placed differently from the original file. I'll use `pdfpages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pagestyle{fancy}` is missing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{centering}
\geometry{width =108.5mm,height=170mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[noprint]{booklet}
%\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet}%
%\nofiles
\pagespersignature{4}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{My special header}}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \setpdftargetpages
    \clearpage page1
    \clearpage page2
    \clearpage page3
    \clearpage page4
\end{document}
```